# Userscript that automatically runs on document-start

Tags: userscripts

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Button
// @run-at        document-start
// @include        *
// @grant         none
// @noframes
// @version 0.0.1
// ==/UserScript==
(function () {
var button = document.createElement("Button")
button.innerHTML = "Title"
button.style = "top:0px;right:0px;position:absolute"
button.style.background='#4CAF50'
document.body.appendChild(button)
var don = document.querySelector('button')
button.onclick = function() { 
alert('Hey') }
})()
```

Script to auto add button on everysite

Trying to inject above script through adguard extension as local title.user.js

But it wasn't working

if i load this script locally it doesnt work
but if i upload it somewhere and load it via url it works

Also on some websites it is not working  is it possible that site is blocking javascript injection. If so how to bypass that and run this script on such websites

Ok seems like the website i am trying to inject is arabic and has right to left text and maybe some overlay html and hence button is not visible but when i changed right to left in above code it worked

But still adguard not injecting above code from local user.js only from remote url

Script also not working on stackoverflow.com itself

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, `document.body` is likely undefined, because your meta block `@run-at` is set to `document-start`. Try `document-end` instead.

Either that, or you should change `document.body` to `document.documentElement`.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        New script - stackoverflow.com
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @include     *
// @grant       none
// @version     1.0
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(() => {
  const button = document.createElement('Button');
  button.innerHTML = 'Title';
  button.style = 'top:0px;right:0px;position:fixed;z-index:10000;';
  button.style.background = '#4CAF50';
  document.documentElement.appendChild(button);
  button.onclick = () => {
    alert('Hey');
  };
})();
```

Comment: script doesnt work locally but when i uploaded on gist and load it works. But on somer websites with non english languages button doesnt appear

Comment: What do you mean locally? Care to share some websites that the script doesn't work on?

Comment: there are some private russian sites on which javascripts dont work. Not only this but any script. Since its provate i cannot share its url

Comment: it doesnt work on stackoverflow. script us runnning on all websites but not on stackoverflow

Comment: I have updated my answer. The reason it didn't work on stackoverflow is because another element was covering it, solved by `z-index`. Also, I replaced `position`'s value to `fixed`, I thought it may be something you would want.

Comment: still doesnt work via adguard works manually. injected in url bar. But  adding zindex breaks the scripts on other websites on which in was previously running

Comment: I really don't understand your comment. Are you on PC? Which browser? Which user script manager?